# Garbage collector in Common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is SBCL or CMUCL garbage collector available in Lisp implementation?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Lisp is a GC'd language. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Makes sense to me. The GC in CMUCL (inherited by SBCL) is written in C. As far as I know, there is no Lisp implementation of it.

Comment: I think you would need a non-garbage-collected Lisp system as a basis for a Lisp implementation of a garbage collector to make sense.

Comment: @Svante: wouldn't it be enough if the Lisp-based GC reclaims more memory than it conses?

Comment: Why would you need a non-GC Lisp for this to make sense?  The code generator (IIRC) is in Lisp, so once you've bootstrapped, if you've got primitives that can generate the opcodes which represent your GC, it's just as possible to implement the GC in Lisp as in C.  Maybe not as easy or straightforward, though.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

SBCL exposes some of its GC functionality: http://john.freml.in/sbcl-optimise-gc

Comment: +1 Even though the question is not very well formed, this article is very interesting and related.

Answer (score 9):

Both of them provide garbage collection.

See [this](http://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/extensions.html#toc30) for CMUCL and [this](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Garbage-Collection.html) for SBCL.

Quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29):

> Garbage collection was invented by
>   John McCarthy around 1959 to solve
>   problems in Lisp.

Every Common Lisp implementation, must have garbage collection defined, since any standard implementation must comply to Common Lisp ANSI standard.

Answer (score 3):

Both of them have GC available.
Like with any conformant Common Lisp implementation, you can do `(gc :full t)` to instruct garbage collector to collect all your unreachable objects.

Comment: Where is this `gc` function mentioned in the ANSI Common Lisp standard?

Comment: @Flux It's not.  The SBCL manual says this is not specified by ANSI: https://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Garbage-Collection